# Generics type parameter wildcard

Tags: hhvm, hacklang

I would like to create an abstract class which takes a type parameter and the constructor of that class should be passed another Action eg.

```
abstract class Action<Tc> {
    public function __construct(private ?Action<*> $onSuccess = null) {}
}
```

How can I express a type parameter wildcard ie. "?" (Java) or "_" (Scala) in Hack?

Comment: I'm no expert in Hack, but it seems to me that your setup is equivalent to having `Action` inherit from a monomorphic class, say `ActionBase`, which exposes the interface used by all `Action<*>`. If you are designing that code, you could refactor your action class that way.

Answer (score 4):

Hack doesn't have wildcard type parameters right now, so the closest you can get is actually specifying a dummy type parameter that you don't actually need, e.g.,

```
abstract class Action<Tc, Ta> {
  public function __construct(private ?Action<Ta> $onSuccess = null) {}
  // ...
}
```

Depending on how exactly you use the `$onSuccess` member variable, you may want it to be some specific subclass of `Action<T>` to be determined later, and so you may want something like this:

```
abstract class Action<Tc, Ta, To as Action<Ta>> {
  public function __construct(private ?To $onSuccess = null) {}
  // ...
}
```

However, I question whether the "dummy" types above above are really a dummy -- the vast, vast majority of use cases of `Action<T>` are going to care what exactly the `T` is, otherwise how exactly would you use the `Action<T>`? (There are certainly rare cases where you don't care about the `T` at a callsite, but they are, well, rare and so I encourage you to consider whether that is actually your case as you build out this functionality.)

Comment: the behaviour makes total sense given your comment regarding desugaring on Github [link](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/3183). However Action<Tc, Ta> won't work as private ?Action<Ta> $onSuccess = null is missing the first type argument required for Action. Which brings us back to wildcards. You are right, in my case a type constraint ie. 'as' will solve the issue eg. abstract class Action<Tc as Config> ... private Action<Config> $onSuccess = null. I guess higher kinded type support is non-trivial to add. I wish I had time to hack around in the type checker code and offer a PR... :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about a wildcard, but could this achieve what you want?

```
<?hh
    abstract class Action<T1 as Action, T2> {
        public function __construct(private ?T1 $onSuccess = null, private ?T2 $bla = null) {}
    }

    class ActionA<T1 as Action, T2> extends Action<T1, T2> {}
    class ActionB<T1 as Action, T2> extends Action<T1, T2> {}
    class ActionC<T1 as Action, T2> extends Action<T1, T2> {}

    $action = new ActionA(new ActionB(new ActionC(null)));

    var_dump($action);
```

When I run this against HHVM 3.1.0, I get:

```
object(ActionA)#1 (2) {
  ["onSuccess":"Action":private]=>
  object(ActionB)#2 (2) {
    ["onSuccess":"Action":private]=>
    object(ActionC)#3 (2) {
      ["onSuccess":"Action":private]=>
      NULL
      ["bla":"Action":private]=>
      NULL
    }
    ["bla":"Action":private]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["bla":"Action":private]=>
  NULL
}
```

And the 3.1.0 type checker also returns "No errors!".

However, the `T1 as Action` statement on the abstract class doesn't appear to be enforcing. For instance, I can change the instantiation line to:

```
$action = new ActionA(new ActionB(new ActionC(new DateTime())));
```

And it hums along fine, with the typechecker returning no errors still. And this is after taking the class definitions out into their own file with `<?hh // strict`.

So not really your answer, but perhaps close? The behavior above might suggest Hack has some issues with this sort of pattern?

Comment: `T1 as Action` omits the type parameter to `Action<T>`, and so won't work in strict, and generally isn't a good idea. The `T1 as Action` is "enforcing" only in the typechecker, which means only as far as the typechecker can see -- HHVM has erasure semantics right now for generics and so can't enforce at runtime. I suspect your code is at toplevel or you've forgotten the hhi files, so we can't see that `DateTime` isn't an `Action<T>`.